# Insert Identity using Microsoft.EntityFramework.Sqlite.Core

Tags: database, sqlite, entity-framework-core, sql-insert, auto-increment

How would I go about modifying my Add method so it inserts a new identity each time it performs an insert. Is there a clean LINQ syntax way to do this without using hardcoded SQL?

Here is the method that saves the data to the SQLite table via Entity Framework

```
   public static void Add(CreditCardTableData creditCard)
        {
            using var context = new SqliteContext();
            var entity = context.CreditCards.Add(creditCard);
            entity.State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Here is the class representing the table data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DebtRefresh.Domain.Data.DatabaseTables
{
    public class CreditCardTableData
    {
        public int CreditCardTableId { get; set; }
        public int CreditCardType { get; set; }
        public string AccountNickName { get; set; }
        public float CreditLine { get; set; }
        public float OwingBalance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [DatabaseGenerated Attribute](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute) on the Primary key Property

> **Identity**: ValueGeneratedOnAdd

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int CreditCardTableId { get; set; }
```

Comment: These two attributes use ```using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;```

Comment: Excellent! I have it all implemented and working on my project at https://github.com/encouragingapps/DebtRefresh   I am also using data annotations to generate Foreign Keys as well.